# Arduino Protothreads by Example

Tags: programming, threads

I am trying to get Arduino working with [Protothreads](http://dunkels.com/adam/pt/) and wanted to confirm I have the basic setup correct. If I have understood the API correctly, then the following code should be what I need to start 2 concurrent threads from inside an Arduino program:

```
#include <pt.h>

static struct pt t1, t2;

void setup() {
    PT_INIT(&t1);
    PT_INIT(&t2);
}

void loop() {
    doSomething(&t1, 500);
    doSomethingElse(&t2, 500);
}

static int doSomething(struct pt *pt, int interval) {
    PT_BEGIN(pt);
    sleep(100);
    PT_END(pt);
}

static int doSomethingElse(struct pt *pt, int interval) {
    PT_BEGIN(pt);
    sleep(250);
    PT_END(pt);
}
```

Does anyone see anything that jumps out at them as missing or wrong?

Comment: What is `sleep()` ?

Answer (score 2):

Check [this example](http://harteware.blogspot.de/2010/11/protothread-and-arduino-first-easy.html): rather than sleep(), it uses PT_WAIT_UNTIL

```
  while(1) {
      PT_WAIT_UNTIL(pt, millis() - timestamp > interval );
      timestamp = millis();
      doSomething();
  }
```

That should be the proto-thread way of waiting: PT_WAIT_UNTIL will make sure that your thread sleeps in a way that allows other threads to run.

The rest looks fine, but I have not tried to run the code.

Comment: Just to add to the understanding (or confusion), PT_WAIT_UNTIL blocks the execution or "yield" to the other threads. You can see its difference from `sleep` which blocks everyone. The `while(1)` "re-arms" the thread again, once `dosomething()` finishes. Here is some C switch-while hackery going on. (see http://dunkels.com/adam/pt/expansion.html)

Answer (score 0):

Why reinvent the wheel? There are libraries that can do just that for you.
For example
**[ArduinoThread](https://github.com/ivanseidel/ArduinoThread)**. I tried it out and did not need to keep looking further. There are also [Wiring](http://wiring.org.co/download/) and [SoftTimer](https://github.com/prampec/arduino-softtimer) but I did not try those.