# Multithreading with Arduino

Tags: programming, c++

Well I've just started learning the concept of multithreading with C++ and immediately a bunch of questions came to mind about the possibility of using multithreading with microcontrollers in general and Arduino specifically.

So, is it possible to use multithreading on any type of Arduino boards?

Comment: By multithreaded, do you also mean concurrent? If you don't, Interrupt routines triggered by a timer at even intervals can cover a lot of similar functionality on AVR processors.

Comment: You could try this library https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Arduino-Scheduler

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In [Cosa](https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Cosa) you can find the following support for concurrent programming:

1. [Events](https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Cosa/blob/master/cores/cosa/Cosa/Event.hh), interface interrupt service routines
2. [Jobs](https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Cosa/blob/master/cores/cosa/Cosa/Job.hh), delayed, [periodic](https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Cosa/blob/master/cores/cosa/Cosa/Periodic.hh) or [alarm](https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Cosa/blob/master/cores/cosa/Cosa/Alarm.hh) functions with us, ms and seconds level timers (Watchdog, RTT or RTC).
3. [FSM](https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Cosa/blob/master/cores/cosa/Cosa/FSM.hh), object-state function
4. [ProtoThreads](https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Cosa/blob/master/libraries/ProtoThread/ProtoThread.hh), object-state pointer
5. [Threads](https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Cosa/blob/master/libraries/Nucleo/Thread.hh), Semaphores, etc, multiple stacks
6. [UML](https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Cosa-UML) Capsules and Connectors, dependency driven programming

There are plenty examples on how to use these. A good starting point is the [Blink](https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Cosa/tree/master/examples/Blink) sketches. There is even a [multi-threading Blink](https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Cosa/blob/master/examples/Blink/CosaBlinkThread/CosaBlinkThread.ino) example with a thread that does the LED on/off and a controller thread that periodically changes the blink period. The thread stack size is only 64 bytes and it runs even on an ATtiny.

With all the AVR internal hardware modules (such as SPI, TWI, UART, etc) there is plenty of opportunities for concurrency.

A [Scheduler](https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Arduino-Scheduler) library for the Arduino core is also available. This is a port of the Cosa Threads. Please see github for further details.

Cheers!

Comment: Of what order is the memory overhead of Cosa? 100 KB flash and 20 KB RAM?

Comment: Depends on what you use/include. In general the "overhead" is less than the Arduino core for similar functionality. Best way to find out is to run some of the example sketches.

Answer (score 3):

The really quick answer is "maybe" – it depends on what you mean by "Arduino" and what you mean by "thread." The answer is likely to be different for the AVR based Arduinos (Uno et al.) vs. the ARM based Arduinos (Due et al.) – I would expect there to be much better hardware support for "real" threads on the ARM processors. Another question you'd want to answer is "why threads?" Do you want the abstraction to help you organize your code? Or do you actually need "real" threads?

Before there was hardware thread support (e.g., the mid-80s) there are user thread implementations, it seems possible that they might be adaptable to run even on an AVR. I would expect it to be something of a project.

There is a threads package called [Protothreads](http://dunkels.com/adam/pt) which may be interesting. The description says "Protothreads are extremely lightweight stalkless threads designed for severely memory constrained systems." I found [another question asking about simple usage](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/12411/arduino-protothreads-by-example) of Protothreads, so it seems that you may find some other users of the package.

You may also find some useful information in this Stack Exchange [question on threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145321/implementing-a-user-level-threads-package), a quick search for "C user threads" found [this implementation](http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~jones/opsys/threads) on the first page – and I'm sure there are many more.

A search on "Arduino threads" found several more interesting looking links:

- [How can I create multiple running threads?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/286/how-can-i-create-multiple-running-threads)
- [Arduino Thread package on GitHub](https://github.com/ivanseidel/ArduinoThread)
- http://www.kwartzlab.ca/2010/09/arduino-multi-threading-librar/
- http://forums.trossenrobotics.com/showthread.php?5923-Multithreading-(Parallel-loops)-on-an-Arduino

If you just want threads, a small and inexpensive board, and I/O pins it might be worth considering a Raspberry Pi – Linux has thread support.

Comment: Good answer. It also might be worth noting that even with hardware thread support, an OS or at least some software will layer will probably need to manage and schedule the threads.

Comment: @Mlagma: As far as I can tell, each link in this answer shows an implementation of threads that are statically compiled into the user's program. The Arduino runs only that one program. Can you give even one example of an OS or other software layer, other than the user program?

Comment: @Mlagma, it could be as simple as something like coroutines and interrupts. I'm not expecting to find much beyond maybe a library that implements a basic scheduler – but I haven't found even that.

Answer (score 3):

There's one Arduino-like product that certainly could enable multi-threading, as it is multi-core: the [Shield Buddy TC275](https://www.rs-online.com/designspark/bringing-multicore-to-the-arduino-world-with-shieldbuddy-tc275).

[image: Core setup and loop functions]

So basically you have three `setup()` functions, and three `loop()` functions. True multi-threading.

Comment: +1 for finding this. Excellent board, but not cheap. However, it would give [AeroQuad](http://aeroquad.com/) a new lease of life..!

Comment: Yeah it's been on my radar for a while but the cost... I hope Chinese clone-makers find it soon :-)

Comment: It's not as compatible as I initially thought though, for reasons that are, _now_, obvious. A simple recompilation may not be sufficient. It will depend on the complexity of the code, i.e. if assembler has been used. See [Has anyone used a Shield Buddy (en lieu of a Arduino Mega2560) as the RAMPS 1.4 host board?](http://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/3410/has-anyone-used-a-shield-buddy-en-lieu-of-a-arduino-mega2560-as-the-ramps-1-4)

Comment: Yeah, ASM could be a problem. Plus, adjusting the code to a 3-core environment, even without ASM, would require some work. But I think for a new project, it could be indeed interesting.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Atomthreads](https://www.google.mn/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://atomthreads.com/&ved=0ahUKEwizhomMgsrRAhXMHZQKHV74DcAQFggYMAA&usg=AFQjCNGsxGMmrzZ5XhSCrSidilYeNhcdwg&sig2=EUhC4i0J711ypa5OhK2o7g) on Atmega128, it is very lightweight with minimum overhead. Have task scheduler, mutex, semaphores and queue. Code is portable but might require some configuration to use with Arduino IDE (I use Atmel Studio). I primarily use task scheduler, never had problems. Just checked, the development is still active.

Comment: Re: *"very lightweight"*. Can you quantify that? Is it 8 KB of flash and 600 bytes of memory?